# SQL Table that calculates values from another SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create an dynamic table that picks up 1st 5 columns from static table and multiply it by a value field.

**1.** static table `(Cases):`

```
Column A; Column B; Column C; Column D; Column E; Value; Jan (cases);...;Dec(cases)
```

**2.** Dynamic Table `(value * cases by month)`

```
Column A; Column B; Column C; Column D; Column E; Jan (value * cases);...;Dec(value * cases)
```

In excel i would just time cell by cell next to it. But i want sql to create/update database every time new static file is uploaded.

**ok update** 
after reviewing i need something a bit different, i need to take 2 tables and accumulate them by each other 
one table would be `cases` and other in `product value`
`cases table:`

 Account; Channel; [PROD CODE]*(this is my p. key)*; **Jan; Feb; Mar; Apr; May; Jun; Jul; Aug; Sep; Oct; Nov; Dec**

`price table:`

Year; SKU *(this is my p. key)*; [Product Name]; **Jan; Feb; Mar; Apr; May; Jun; Jul; Aug; Sep; Oct; Nov; Dec;**
the number value sits in individual months. 
In another words i need 
`cases table`.`JAN` * `price table`.`Jan` where `cases table`.`primary key` = `price table`.`primary key`

Comment: Please post sample output

Comment: Be careful with your wording. You probably do not want to _create a database` in every case. So you actually have several questions: a) how do you update/create a table from values in another table. b) What is preferable: update or (re-)create. c) How shall this step be triggered?

Comment: in terms of update i would get monthly files that need to go into database, then i want to calculate and link it into internal database.  Process would be all about receiving data in flat files from managers and uploading them to SQL this is when i would like for all transformations to the data happened

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at computed [columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Or, if you need to include Another table in the calculation, you could create a user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue(INT @code, INT @rec)
RETURNS INT
AS ...
```

Then you would alter your table adding the column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Mytbl
   ADD MyCalcCol AS dbo.GetValue(CodeVal, RecVal)
```

Another thought.. why not just create a view, or even an indexed view.

```
CREATE VIEW vwTableYear AS 
   SELECT [Month number in cases]*[price of product] AS MonthlyValue 
   FROM myTableYear
```

Comment: creating a view would be a good option although how do i tell it to take columns from and table and then multiply it by certain value

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then someting like tihs, which combines data from two tables: 
CREATE VIEW vwMyView AS 
 SELECT a.col1, b.col1*2 
 FROM MyTbl1 AS a 
 INNER JOIN MyTbl2 AS b ON a.id = b.Id

Comment: I managed to get in in my table by doing this ALTER TABLE myTableYear ADD [MonthlyValue] AS [Month number in cases]*[price of product]

Comment: but instead of having it in same table i would like to sql to create a new view with those details

Comment: OK, sorry if I don't understand fully, but are you perhaps looking for this:  <br/>

CREATE VIEW vwTableYear AS SELECT [Month number in cases]*[price of product] AS MonthlyValue FROM myTableYear <br/>

Then you could access the value through the view. Just add more columns to the view as neccesary.  <br/>

I hope that helps you!